# Asset Symbols not being generated for a project not created by Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have this SwiftUI project created with Xcode 13.

In theory, Xcode 15 generates asset symbols automatically.

So, I should be able to create a color in the assets' folder called `myFavoriteColor` and use it in code like

```
Color(.myFavoriteColor)
```

But it is not working.

In the build settings, I have both `Generate Asset Symbols` and `Generate Swift Asset Symbol Extensions` YES.

I have turned those to NO and to YES, to see if Xcode would enable it, but as expected, it did not work.

I also have `Generate Swift Asset Symbol Framework Support` as `SwiftUI UIKit AppKit`.

The asset symbols are generated if I create a new project with Xcode 15.

Is there any way to make it work for older projects?